# Module not found: can't resolve' redux-thunk ' error I have tried the solutions but it does not happen.What is the solution?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, thunk

I tried all the commands for redux but it doesn't work:how do you think the solution is. These are the commands I tried

```
yarn add react-redux
yarn add reduxjs / Redux-thunk#master
npm install --save Redux react-redux
npm install redux -- save
npm i redux -- save
yarn add redux-thunk
```

index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware,compose} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/rootReducer';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {reduxFirestore,getFirestore} from 'redux-firestore'
import {reactReduxFirebase,getFirebase} from 'react-redux-firebase'
import fbConfig from './config/fbConfig';


const store=createStore(rootReducer,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({getFirebase,getFirestore})),
        reduxFirestore(fbConfig),
        reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig)
    ));


ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "omaga-yazilim",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^npm i --save react-router4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "firebase": "^7.8.1",
    "jest-leak-detector": "^25.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-redux-firebase": "^3.1.1",
    "react-router": "^4.4.0-beta.8",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.4.0-beta.6",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-firestore": "^0.12.0",
    "redux-thunk": "reduxjs/redux-thunk#master",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are using the **master** branch from **redux-thunk**?

Comment: Also you have `start` script as a dependency. That needs to be removed. And the version `@testing-library/jest-dom` is an npm command instead of an actual version.

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same problem but I run the command line:

> npm install --save redux-thunk

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to use [our new official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org).  The [`configureStore` function](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore) will automatically set up the store correctly, including adding the thunk middleware by default.  Given that you're trying to use React-Redux-Firebase, you can do that by using the [`getDefaultMiddleware` API](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware#customizing-the-included-middleware):

```js
const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware: [...getDefaultMiddleware({
        thunk: {
            extraArgument: {getFirebase,getFirestore}
        }
    })],
    enhancers: [reduxFirestore(fbConfig), reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig)]
})
```

Comment: I did what you said, he didn't give the thunk error, but Module not found: can't resolve gave the 'react-redux' error.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with this and this is how i resolved it:

Stop the server:Ctrl C in terminal.

Open package.json and manually add:

```
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
```

then in the terminal cd into the project and install redux thunk:

```
yarn add redux-thunk
```

**restart the server:**

```
yarn start
```

More details about redux thunk can be found on this link:

[ReduxThunk-Github](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue...and this is how I resolved it...

Stop the server Ctrl + C

open package.json

and remove the available redux-thunk version and replace like below...

```
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
```

and then go to terminal and install the redux-thunk using following command...

```
npm install redux-thunk
```

and then start the server

```
npm start
```